# Unable to perform an action if a view isn't present when clicking a link

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I currently am doing up a very simple site. It has the following structure:

/

-routes

--index.js

--login.js

--logout.js

-views

--index.jade

--login.jade

This site utilizes the latest version node.js, with the jade templating engine and express if that helps as well.

Basically I have it where when you click on index, your'e presented with the option to login, where it will process the login template, and check your credentials. With logout, I want it to just go to the .js file, nuke the session that I have, and reroute to the index view. However I can't seem to get the routing done correctly, it acts like it's expecting a view, but as there is none, I think that's why it's failing. Is there any way to say "no there's no view, jsut process the js file?"

EDIT: app.js file contents

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');

var indexRoute = require('./routes/index');
var loginRoute = require('./routes/login');
var logoutRoute = require('./routes/logout');

var app = express();

var db = require("mongojs").connect("localhost:27017/acl", ["comments"]);

app.use(function(req,res,next){
req.db = db;
next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.user = req.user || null;
next();
});

app.use('/', indexRoute);
app.post('/loginForm', loginRoute);
app.use('/login', loginRoute);
app.use('/logout', logoutRoute);
```

logout.js

```
var express = require('express);
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
   if (req.session === undefined) {
      res.location("index");
      res.redirect("/");
   } else {
      if (res.session.role == "guest") {
         res.location("index");
         res.redirect("/");
      } else {
         req.session = null;
         res.render('home', {title: "express" });       
      }
   }
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You probably want to add more details about which framework and so on you are using.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Apologies. Added to tags and description

Comment: probably need to see your `app.js` file, or if its not named that, whatever file starts the server.

Comment: @pseudonym117 You got it.

Comment: think i have an idea, but need to see logout.js to be sure.

Comment: also, as a general style, node apps do not use semicolons unless absolutely needed. has nothing to do with your issue, just a general styling comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your error is here:

```
...
} else {
    req.session = null;
    res.render('home', {title: "express" });       
}
...
```

I believe you just want to do exactly the same thing as in the other parts of the if statement - redirect to the index.

On another note,

```
res.location("index");
res.redirect("/");
```

can and most likely should be changed to just

```
res.redirect("/")
```

Also there seems to be a typo on your first line in `logout.js` - you are missing an end quote on your `require('express')`